# Is there a time limit to elect the Speaker of the House of Representatives?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, speaker

As Kevin McCarthy is approaching his fifth defeat for a role as Speaker of the House of Representatives, I am interested to know whether there is a time limit (or special measures in place) until somebody must assume the role, in the event that the vote is unsuccessful each time.

Comment: Yeah, 2 years, then other people start trying again. But seriously, despite Einstein's characterization of doing the same thing 5 times and expecting a different result, there's no hard time limit for electing a speaker. Sometimes it's taken dozens of rounds, though the trend of the past century is 1 round...

Comment: Having Congress paralyzed by this issue for two years does not sound like a universally bad outcome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will go to penalty kicks soon.

Comment: The yardstick here is the [34th Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Speaker_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections#December_1855_%E2%80%93_February_1856), which took 2 months and _133_ ballots to elect a speaker (Dec 1855 - Feb 1856)

Comment: What I wonder is: If McCarthy does give up the fight, is there some other Republican who has enough support to win in his place? Or would we just get another impasse with different candidates?

Comment: @dandavis This is America, though, so it would need to be something like 2-point conversion attempts, free throws, or 3-on-3 sudden death.

Comment: @BobaFit - In the short term, I agree. The problem is the debt ceiling will likely need to be raised sometime around Q3 2023. If Congress can't pass legislation to do that, the US Government will start defaulting on its debts, soldiers and government employees will quit getting paid, etc. which will have debilitating financial repercussions across the US economy both immediately and going forward well after the issue gets resolved. And that's just one example. The entire nation kind of depends on the existence of a working House to function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no **official** time limit, just a point where the question becomes irrelevant.  It is theoretically possible for the entire two-year term of this Congress to pass without ever electing a Speaker, at which point the next set of Member-elects can vote on a Speaker for that new session of Congress.  The problem with letting the entire term pass is that the House can't do anything *else* (even swear in the rest of its members) until the Speaker is elected, so going two years without one means two years of no legislation passing, even the uncontroversial things that pass by unanimous consent.

So the **practical** limit is the first "must-pass" bill's deadline - the first bill which will shut down the government or otherwise cause mass disruption if it hasn't passed.  [This page](https://www.crfb.org/blogs/upcoming-congressional-fiscal-policy-deadlines) lists several upcoming fiscal bills - whether they're "must-pass" really depends on what Congress considers to be such.  For example, bad things will likely happen if the debt ceiling isn't raised by the time the government hits the current one (probably this Summer) and the US defaults on its debt, but there's no *requirement* that it be passed.

Comment: I would say that two years is the **official** time limit as that is when the terms of the current members-elect (not members; they're not members until they select a Speaker) ends.

Comment: That list is missing more mundane matters—like paying Congressional staff. My understanding is that won’t happen unless we have a Congress, and that won’t happen without a Speaker.

Comment: I don't quite think that must-pass can completely wedge. If the senate passes it first; there's a notice sent to the house that interrupts whatever is on the floor. They can take that opportunity to decide to vote on it, since there's no filibuster.

Comment: @Joshua That's an interesting question.  If there's two "takes priority over other things" things pending, which wins?

Comment: @DavidHammen - But that's not a limit in the sense of "must be done by this point".  It's more "must be done by this point if it's going to happen at all".  I added a bit to reference that.

Comment: @Joshua - I've turned that into part of a separate question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77523/exactly-what-if-anything-can-the-house-do-without-a-speaker

Comment: The Debt Ceiling looks like it will need raising again around Q3. I'd say that's a hard "must pass" limit, except [one of the demands](https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/3799320-lawmakers-say-mccarthy-speaker-fight-portends-debt-ceiling-crisis/) of the Republicans voting against McCarthy is that he cause this exact same kind of crisis again over the Debt Ceiling vote. So either way it looks like we'll be right back here then.

Answer (score 10):

There is no time limit and the votes will continue until a speaker is elected as nothing can happen in the house until that happens. It is possible that they can change the vote from a majority of all votes cast to a plurality and they have done that in the past.

[Speaker elections with multiple ballots](https://history.house.gov/People/Office/Speakers-Multiple-Ballots/)

This shows that there have been 14 speaker elections with multiple ballots one taking 133 votes.

[Speaker of the 34th congress](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/longest-elect-speaker-house/story?id=96183135)

> The record for most rounds of votes, according to the Office of the
> Historian of the House, is the 34th Congress, when Rep. Nathaniel
> Prentice Banks of Massachusetts was only elected speaker after 133
> rounds and some two months of voting.

In this case it took two months of voting to get it done.

[Plurality Votes](https://thehill.com/homenews/house/3792997-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-house-speaker-election/)

> Dire circumstances could lead to unusual procedures. Twice before, in
> 1849 and 1856, the House agreed to a resolution that allowed a Speaker
> to be elected by a plurality. That move was something of a last
> resort, though, and came after 59 and 129 failed ballots. A majority
> of the whole House would need to agree to that resolution.

Comment: Plurality voting will not happen, because the plurality winner is a Democrat.

Comment: @SimonRichter I am not saying it will happen just that it is one option to end the deadlock.

Comment: @SimonRichter There does seem to be a road that leads there though.  We ended up in the current situation in part because McCarthy played chicken with the freedom caucus assuming when ultimately the votes were cast they'd fall in line.  There is a scenario where brinkmanship is played again and assume that if not voting for him would literally give control of the house to the Democrats, that would be too far for the holdouts.

Comment: @Chuu that is something I have heard talk about though it does come with the warning that some of the holdouts appear to prefer the democrat choice over McCarthy.

Comment: @JoeW In an interview yesterday, Jake Auchincloss seriously suggested that some of the never-Kevins should vote for Jeffries. It would only take 6 of them.

Comment: @Barmar Correct as Jeffries is at 212 votes and only 6 votes short.

Comment: 213 after the upcoming special election in Virginia; very Blue district where the member died already.

Comment: @Barmar Auchincloss is a Democrat, of course he would say that. The "never-Kevins" are mostly hardline Republicans, mostly from very red districts. There is 0% chance they'll vote for Jeffries. Some Republicans (whether "never-Kevins" or not,) however, could theoretically agree with Democrats to elect a more moderate/less partisan Republican or a even someone from outside the House who is neither a Democrat nor a Republican, though that too seems like a remote chance.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The special election is not happening until February 21st and if the speaker still has not been picked by that point we have major problems.

Comment: @reirab I think the problem the holdouts have with McCarthy is that he's too moderate, they want someone more extreme like themselves.

Comment: @Barmar Right. Which is all the more reason they'd not allow Jeffries to become Speaker. I meant, though, that other Republicans could strike a deal with Democrats to get a majority without the support of either McCarthy or the "never-Kevin" crowd. Or McCarthy himself could even broker such a deal, though that seems even less likely.

Comment: @reirab Right, we're probably more likely to get some of the OK-Kevins to switch ranks than the Never-Kevins. That would also be the result if they agreed to change to plurality.

Comment: @Barmar True, but it's exceptionally unlikely that any Republican, moderate or otherwise, would agree to change to plurality under the current circumstances.

Comment: @reirab The real problem is that practically every scenario to get out of this mess is "unlikely". Someone has to give.

Comment: @Barmar Agree, but it won't be a "majority party hands speakership to minority party on a silver platter" type of giving. A compromise of some sort is definitely possible. Handing Democrats the speakership, however, would be pretty much at the bottom of the list of possibilities, as it would be political suicide for any Republican, both with their voters and with their party leadership.

Comment: @Barmar You are right something has to give but it is still really early in the process and no one is ready to give yet.

Comment: @SimonRichter The plurality winner is not a Democrat, because if the rules allowed a win by plurality McCarthy would get a majority. The Republican hard-liners don’t want McCarthy to win, but they want Jeffries to win even less.

Comment: @MikeScott As of the 11th vote McCarthy has yet to be the plurality winner. As it stands he would need 13 of the 20 Republicans who are not voting for him to switch their votes to him for that to happen. As of the last count the Democrats had the plurality winner by 12 votes.

Comment: @JoeW The rogue Republicans are voting as they do because the effective choice is between McCarthy or chaos, and they like the chaos. If the rules were changed to allow a plurality win then the choice would be between McCarthy or Jeffries, and so they’d have to vote for McCarthy or get Jeffries.

Comment: @MikeScott As I have already said before I am not saying that they will change to a plurality vote just that it is an option and has been used in the past.